# wordpress ignores featured image

Tags: wordpress, header, twenty-ten-theme

I created a wordpress theme based on the classic twentyten theme.
I changed the size of the header images in the functions.php but apart from that I didnt mess around with the custom header stuff. Now wordpress is ignoring it when I assign featured images to pages and instead only displays the background selected in the header settings.
The size of the image doesnt seem to have anything to do with the problem. I have tried using the exact image size and larger images, they are always ignored...

Thanks if you can help!

PS. Here a link to the website: http://stuck-mueller.de/beta/

here is the code from the functions.php:

```
// The custom header business starts here.

$custom_header_support = array(
    // The default image to use.
    // The %s is a placeholder for the theme template directory URI.
    'default-image' => '%s/images/headers/path.jpg',
    // The height and width of our custom header.
    'width' => apply_filters( 'twentyten_header_image_width', 960 ),
    'height' => apply_filters( 'twentyten_header_image_height', 240 ),
    // Support flexible heights.
    'flex-height' => true,
    // Don't support text inside the header image.
    'header-text' => false,
    // Callback for styling the header preview in the admin.
    'admin-head-callback' => 'twentyten_admin_header_style',
);

add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $custom_header_support );

if ( ! function_exists( 'get_custom_header' ) ) {
    // This is all for compatibility with versions of WordPress prior to 3.4.
    define( 'HEADER_TEXTCOLOR', '' );
    define( 'NO_HEADER_TEXT', true );
    define( 'HEADER_IMAGE', $custom_header_support['default-image'] );
    define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH', $custom_header_support['width'] );
    define( 'HEADER_IMAGE_HEIGHT', $custom_header_support['height'] );
    add_custom_image_header( '', $custom_header_support['admin-head-callback']   );
    add_custom_background();
}

// We'll be using post thumbnails for custom header images on posts and pages.
// We want them to be 940 pixels wide by 198 pixels tall.
// Larger images will be auto-cropped to fit, smaller ones will be ignored. See header.php.
set_post_thumbnail_size( $custom_header_support['width'], $custom_header_support['height'], true );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the apply_filters() just assign the width and height to integers like:

```
'width' => 960,
'height' => 240,
```

[Check out the codex here for more info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers)